# Is there a reason to prefer the standard deviation of log differences over just the standard deviation of a difference?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, logarithm

For example, if one is comparing the dispersion of prices of 5 different goods between two countries (assuming they have the same currency), is there a reason one should use the standard deviation, over all 5 goods, of the **log** of the ratio of the price of a good in country X over  the price of the same good in country Y?

I would think that taking logs of this price ratio, between the two countries, may create inaccuracies because the logs are only an approximation to the percent difference in price for the same good in both locations.

Comment: What do you suppose the logs are "only approximating"?

Comment: I understand that the the percent difference is being approximated by the log of the ratio, so that (price of x in A – price of x in B)/price of x in B  is approximated by ln(price of x in A/price of x in B). However, it's not clear to me what the benefit of using logs here is.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  Many would instead think of logarithms as *re-expressing* the percent difference: there's no approximation involved.  It's an alternative way of working with the percent differences.  (This doesn't answer your question, of course.)